# Why is casting the class of a generic to Class<T> unsafe?

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-inference

I'm making a `MethodPointer` class in order to simulate the functionality of function pointers from C++.  At first, I was doing everything with just `Object`s, but then I had a thought -- why not make it truly generic?

The problem came in this constructor, which attempted to call another constructor with the signature `MethodPointer(Class<T> clazz, String methodName, Class<?> ... paramClasses)`:

```
public MethodPointer(T object, String methodName, Class<?> ... paramClasses) {
    this(object.getClass(), methodName, paramClasses);
    this.object = object;
}
```

I assumed this would work just fine, but I received the following compiler error:

```
The constructor MethodPointer<T>(Class<capture#1-of ? extends Object>,
String, Class<?>[]) is undefined
```

So, confused, I did this:

```
public MethodPointer(T object, String methodName, Class<?> ... paramClasses) {
    this((Class<T>) object.getClass(), methodName, paramClasses);
    this.object = object;
}
```

It now compiles, but I receive the following warning:

```
Unchecked cast from Class<capture#1-of ? extends Object> to Class<T>
```

I guess the problem is that I don't understand what `Class<capture#1-of ? extends Object>` means.  I thought that since the type of `T` is inferred from the `T object` parameter that it would be *necessary* that calling `object.getClass()` returns a `Class` object of type `Class<T>`.  Apparently this isn't the case, though.  Can someone clear up my confusion?

---

**Full class declaration and all constructors:**

```
public class MethodPointer<T> {

    //Logger instance
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MethodPointer.class);

    //Object fields
    private final Method method;
    private ArrayList<Object> args = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private T object = null;


    //Constructors
    public MethodPointer(Method method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public MethodPointer(Class<T> clazz, String methodName, Class<?> ... paramClasses) {
        Method theMethod = null;
        try {
            theMethod = clazz.getMethod(methodName, paramClasses);
        }
        catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
            LogUtil.log(LOGGER, Level.ERROR, "Unable to find method " + methodName + " in " + clazz.getSimpleName(), nsme);
        }
        method = theMethod;
    }

    public MethodPointer(T object, String methodName, Class<?> ... paramClasses) {
        this((Class<T>) object.getClass(), methodName, paramClasses);
        this.object = object;
    }
```

Comment: Btw, if you're open to using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), check out their [`Invokable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/Invokable.html) class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SLaks' answer points out that `object.getClass()` decays to `Class<? extends Object>`, to explain the compile error. But it's **not safe** to cast to `Class<T>`.

[`getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) "returns the runtime class" of the object it's called on. For example, if we're inside a `MethodPointer<Number>`, then `object` *is-a* `Number` but its runtime type could be `Integer`, `Double`, etc. That tells us that casting `object.getClass()` to `Class<T>` isn't safe because `Class<Integer>` and `Class<Number>` are different objects, representing different classes - a distinction that seems very relevant to the correctness of what you're trying to do.

So what's the solution? Well, don't cast. Insist on taking a `Class<T>` from the caller.

Comment: +1 The OP can get inconsistent results depending on which constructor is called, if `T` is a non-final type.

Comment: Would using `Class<? extends T>` everywhere help? (other than giving weird results when pointing to shadowed `final` methods)

Comment: @SLaks It would definitely help - casting to that instead would be safe. I actually forgot `getClass` wouldn't return `Class<? extends T>` if you look at my edit history :) Since the OP's using `getMethod`, which also searches superclasses, using a `Class<? extends T>` seems fine - but if he wants to use `getDeclaredMethod` (to find non-public methods), he'll need exactly `Class<T>`.

Comment: @SLaks: even `Class<? extends T>` is technically not safe. Suppose `T` is `List<String>`, then you would have `Class<? extends List<String>>`, which is not safe; only `Class<? extends List>` is safe. With `Class<? extends List<String>>` you can use `.cast()` to cast something without warning to `List<String>`; but the type parameter is not checked.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the warning.  This makes sense for explaining why it's unsafe (which was the initial question).

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `getClass()` ignores type parameters.

The [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) say:

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.

For example, `new ArrayList<String>().getClass()` returns a `Class<? extends ArrayList>`, not `Class<? extends ArrayList<String>>`.

This also means that `getClass()` called on a type parameter decays to a `Class<? extends Object>`.

Comment: Wouldn't the downcast be safe though due to the type parameter `T` being specified in the first parameter to the `MethodPointer` constructor?

Comment: @KevinBowersox: Yes, it is safe, but `getClass()`'s compile-time type specifically ignores type parameters.

Comment: Unsafe doesn't always mean, well, unsafe. All it really means is that the compiler (as constrained by the JLS) can't _confirm_ the type safety.

Comment: Okay, I suppose that makes sense.  Thank you.  But can you explain what this bit means in the `Class` type: `capture#1-of`?  I would get it if it actually just "decayed" straight to the `Class<? extends Object>` instead of that gibberish.

Comment: @JeffGohlke The following may shed some light on what `capture#1-of` means: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Comment: -1 This answer does a good job explaining the compile time error, but the cast isn't safe like you and @yshavit are saying - see my answer.

Comment: @PaulBellora To clarify, I wasn't saying anything about the safety in this particular case, just making a general statement about what unsafe means. The JDK even has some perfectly safe unsafe casts, as I recall.

Comment: @yshavit I'm with you - I mentioned you just to bring it to your attention, since your (upvoted) comment *appears* to support that it's a safe cast.

Comment: Bad mix of pedantic and hurried on my part. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need an specified Class-type, you could use

```
Class<?>
```

for you parameters.

So you have an unbound Type for your classes.

And if you want to get an instance you could use it like this:

```
obj.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(Class<?> parameterTypes)
```